# How can I close a django 1.8 database cursor and connection?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, connection, django-1.8

Here is what I have:

```
from django.db import connection

class Command(BaseCommand):

option_list = BaseCommand.option_list

def handle(self, *labels, **options):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Drop database 
        cursor.execute("drop database if exists test_db;")
        # Create database again
        cursor.execute("create database test_db;")
```

Where in this block can I close the db cursor and connection and what do I call to close them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

I close the connection out of the "with" block with connection.close()
and that solves it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is try to create and close the cursor within each method where query is needed.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.close()
```

So your function should look like this:

```
def handle(self, *labels, **options):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Drop database 
        cursor.execute("drop database if exists test_db;")
        # Create database again
        cursor.execute("create database test_db;")
        #Close the cursor
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: This is closing ONLY the cursor ... I want to be able to close the DATABASE CONNECTION too ... How do I explicitly do that?

Comment: the `cursor` is automatically closed when exiting the `with` block (even on an exception)